# Calculate an conditional share in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider the following data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(a = c("s10","s10","s10","s20","s30"),
                b = c("t10","t40","t30","t20","t60"))
```

I want to get the following data from this data frame:

```
    a   b   c
1:  s10 t10 0.33
2:  s10 t40 0.33
3:  s10 t30 0.33
4:  s20 t20 1
5:  s30 t60 1
```

That is, if the value from column a belongs to multiple values in column b, then I want to calculate the share. For instance, for "s10" in column a, there is three value in column b ("t10", "t40" and "t30"), so the value in column 3 should be: 1/3 = 0.33.

Comment: using `dplyr`: `d %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(c = 1 / n())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option without libraries:

```
d$c <- ave(1:nrow(d), d$a, FUN=function(x) 1/length(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, c := 1/.N, a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(c=1/n())
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   a [3]
  a     b         c
  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1 s10   t10   0.333
2 s10   t40   0.333
3 s10   t30   0.333
4 s20   t20   1    
5 s30   t60   1
```